# How to keep processes running in docker at AWS instance when connected via ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ssh, nohup

I'm working on AWS instance (machine learning task) from my laptop (Linux). I would like run my code and go out from session, stop computer. How can I do it whitout stopping program execution that can take 1 day?

For the moment I use these commands:

`ssh -i $HOME/.ssh/file.pem ubuntu@[IP-AWS]` to connect to AWS instance.

`docker run --gpus all -u $(id -u):$(id -g) -it --rm --name tempo -v /data:/tf [MY_IMAGE] /bin/bash` to open docker image

`python train.py [MY_INSTRUCTIONS] 2>&1 | tee out_file` to run script to run my script

My Script does not use files in my computer, `/data` disk is attached to instance. There is no need to keep computer on.
But if I close terminal, program is stopped.

How can I do the same task: launch script and then disconnect? How can I know when the program stops?

I found `nohup` command, but I did not understand how use it in my case (I'm a beginner).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by running the docker container in the background with -d as discussed here (using `docker run -d`):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31570507/4358503

Also you should remove the -it flags. Those mark the process as 'interactive' so it will ask/wait for user input.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was looking in the wrong direction (how use ```ssh``` instead of good use of ```docker```).

Comment: Np, please mark the answer correct if it helped!